# Standard way to protect library components from being styled by consumer

Tags: css, angular, scope

I am building a UI library in Angular and often designate elements to be styled with generic classes such as `.slider`, or `.form-control`.  The problem I run into is that sometimes the consumer (who uses the library) uses the same classes for its own elements and when he applies styling it inadvertently breaks the library's UI.

Angular does provide scoped classes so that if for instance I have the style:

```
.form-control { line-height: 2em; }
```

then at runtime, Angular has modified it to dynamically add a component specific attribute:

```
.form-control[ng_content0] { line-height: 2em; }
```

And because that attribute is added to the element itself dynamically, my styles don't bleed out and impact the elements of the client who consumes the library.

That's great.  But how do I prevent the reverse?  Basically, how do I use CSS in a way that limits the consumer from breaking things when there is a conflict of class names?  Only thing I've thought about is to prefix all class names with a prefix.  Some kind of janky namespacing:

```
.mylib_form-control { line-height: 2em; }
```

What's the right approach?

Answer (score 2):

> Basically, how do I use CSS in a way that limits the consumer from
>   breaking things when there is a conflict of class names?

I think it's more important to try to prevent a conflict in class names, instead of dealing with what happens if there is one. If there is a conflict, assuming the selectors have the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) the style defined last will win. So, depending on if the consumer adds your library before or after their own styles, that would affect what conflicting rules would apply. If you think your library is super important, you can add !important to all your library styles. Which is a bad idea. You should just try to avoid the conflict.

You could perhaps add a prefix to all your classes, say `beetle-ui` and I would assume the consumer doesn't have any classes that start with that.

You could do something like Semantic UI and for an HTML element to take on the style of the library, it must have the class `ui` in it's class list. Then all your selectors kind of look like:

```
.ui.input {
}
.ui.header {
}
```

The corresponding HTML would like something like:

```
<input class="ui input" />
```

I would do something like my first example, and use [BEM](http://getbem.com/naming/) and define my CSS using [SASS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli) so my syntax can be a bit cleaner and benefit from the prefixing.

```
.beetle-ui-form {
    background-color: grey;
    &__input {
        outline: red;
    }
}
```

Which would generate CSS like:

```
.beetle-ui-form {
    background-color: grey;
}
.beetle-ui-form__input {
    outline: red;
}
```

Comment: I am not worried about conflicting styles bc in such a case, the lib styles are more specific already.  I am worried about the consumer's style breaking the lib when the lib itself uses the same class name but has no matching style.  For eg: the consumer and the lib may both have `.form-control` but the consumer may set a padding on that selector for its own elements whereas the library doesn't. The lib breaks bc it didn't explicitly set a padding=0 of its own (impractical to explicitly set all props on all selectors). Sounds like a class prefix (`bettle-ui`) is what you'd recommend?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience building a component library relies on the balance between easiness of customisation and protecting the component library styles.
I would say that for libraries using a prefix is almost always a good idea.
I also agree with ryanm that use of `!important` is not a good idea, it would not allow to customize any styles for the most part.

In my case library was a crucial / core part of a few projects using it.
That's why me and my coleagues decided to use Sass for styling and conviniently nest all of our class selectors inside of parent id selector which bring specisifity up but don't make much additional work for us.

Also when we style text for our components we tried to style as low as we could so for example if I want to style all of the `<a>` tags inside of a `div` with a class `myParentName` I would do:

```
.myParentClass a {
    color: red;
}
```

instead of

```
.myParentClass {
    color: red;
}
```

In addition to that we created a brief documentation consisting of only around 5 points to help the developers using our library so that they wouldn't override any styles by accident, but on purpose rather.
So it may be a good idea to warn them for example not to use selectors like the ones below on some ocasions because they may affect library styles:

```
.myParentElement > div,
.myParentElement *
```